# FlatMap a mutable list in Spark appln using Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark-Scala Development and trying to get hands dirty so please bear with me if you find the question stupid.

```
Sample dataset

[29430500,1104296400000,1938,F,11,2131,
MutableList([123291654450,1440129600000,100121,0,1440734400000],[234564535,2345129600000,345121,1,14567734400000])
]
```

If you see the last field it's an `Array[]` and I want the output to look like this:-

```
Row 1:
    [29430500,1104296400000,1938,F,11,2131,
    123291654450,1440129600000,100121,0,1440734400000]

Row 2: 
    [29430500,1104296400000,1938,F,11,2131,
    234564535,2345129600000,345121,1,14567734400000]
```

I think I have to do `flatMap` but for some reason, the following code gives this error:

```
def getMasterRdd(sc: SparkContext, hiveContext: HiveContext, outputDatabase:String, jobId:String,MasterTableName:String, dataSourceType: DataSourceType, startDate:Long, endDate:Long):RDD[Row]={}

val Rdd1= ClassName.getMasterRdd(sc, hiveContext, "xyz", "test123", "xyz.abc", DataSourceType.SS, 1435723200000L, 1451538000000L)
Rdd1: holds the sample dataset

val mapRdd1= Rdd1.map(Row => Row.get(6))
val flatmapRdd1 = mapPatientRdd.flatMap(_.split(","))
```

When I hover over `(_.split(","))` I get a suggestion that says the following:

```
Type mismatch, expected:(Any) => TraversableOnce[NotInferedU], actual: (Any) =>Any
```

Comment: Please include the exact error message with your question

Comment: `Error:(29, 53) value split is not a member of Any
    val flatmapPatientRdd = mapPatientRdd.flatMap(_.split(", "))`

Comment: You will get more help if you provide more info ie. what type is the dataset? How did `Rdd1` get constructed?

Comment: edited the original question.. hope this helps..

Comment: @LazyBones: Man you need to use the variable names in the correct manner without the Caps, its a bit confusing !

Comment: I understand your point.. will make sure next time.. but do u see anything wrong i m doing here??

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a better way to structure this (maybe using tuples instead of `List`s) but anyway this works for me:

```
scala>  val myRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(Seq(29430500L,1104296400000L,1938L,"F",11L,2131L,Seq(Seq(123291654450L,1440129600000L,100121L,0L,1440734400000L),Seq(234564535L,2345129600000L,345121L,1L,14567734400000L)))))
myRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Seq[Any]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[11] at parallelize at <console>:27

scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val myRDD2 = myRDD.flatMap(row => {
    val (beginning, end) = (row.dropRight(1), row.last)
    end.asInstanceOf[List[List[Any]]].map(beginning++_)
})

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

myRDD2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Seq[Any]] = MapPartitionsRDD[10] at flatMap at <console>:29

scala> myRDD2.foreach{println}
List(29430500, 1104296400000, 1938, F, 11, 2131, 123291654450, 1440129600000, 100121, 0, 1440734400000)
List(29430500, 1104296400000, 1938, F, 11, 2131, 234564535, 2345129600000, 345121, 1, 14567734400000)
```

Comment: thanks @evan058.. when i add `val myRDD2 = myRDD.flatMap(row => {
    val (beginning, end) = (row.dropRight(1), row.last)
    end.asInstanceOf[List[List[Any]]].map(beginning++_)})` it says **cannot resolve symbol dropRight, last and ++**

Comment: Is your RDD at the beginning of type `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Seq[Any]]`? That is what your sample dataset seems to indicate

Comment: I see, it is type `RDD[Row]`. If you do a `RDD1.map(_.toSeq)` first, then my answer will work

Comment: hi @evan058 same error.. Cannot resolve symbol `(_.toSeq)`

Comment: If `RDD1` is of type `RDD[Row]` then it should work because [`Row` has the `toSeq` method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row). Let me know what the type of `RDD1` is (and maybe add that to the original question).

Comment: its of type RDD[Row] coz I can do 
`val Rdd2= Rdd1.map(Row => Row.get(6))`

Comment: That expression just means that whatever is in your `RDD` has a `get` method. `Row` within the context of your `map` is just a variable name. What version of spark are you using?

Comment: We are using Spark 1.6

Comment: This works for me in Spark 1.6: `scala> rddOfRows.map(_.toSeq)
res14: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Seq[Any]]`

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
rdd.flatMap(row => row.getSeq[String](6).map(_.split(","))
```

Comment: **didn't work**

`val mapRdd1= Rdd1.map(Row => Row.get(6))`
`val flatmapRdd1= mapRdd1.flatMap(row => row.getSeq[String](6).map(_.split(","))`

**Type mismatch, expected:(Any) => TraversableOnce[NotInferedU], actual: (Any) =>Any**